# Typescript Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

In the code below, I want to create a function to collect all the custom event handlers, and it seems error.

But I do use `handlerMap[type] || []` to ensure `handlerList` exists.
What did I miss?

```js
type EventType = 'click' | 'dblclick' | 'mouseup' | 'mousedown' | 'mousemove'

interface EventHandlerSet<P extends EventType> {
  h: (event: HTMLElementEventMap[P]) => void
  ctx: any
}

const handlerMap: { [P in EventType]?: Array<EventHandlerSet<P>> } = {}

function addHandler<P extends EventType>(
  type: P,
  handler: (event: HTMLElementEventMap[P]) => void,
  context?: any,
) {
  const handlerList= handlerMap[type] || []

  // Error here: Object is possibly 'undefined'
  handlerList.push({ h: handler, ctx: context || this })

  handlerMap[type] = handlerList
}
```

PS. Paste the code into TypeScript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) to see the error.

@evayly mentioned, we need to turn on `strictNullChecks`

Comment: I do not get this error. What TS version are you using? You can tell the TSC that you are certain an object exists by using !. `handlerList!.push(...)` or what do you mean?

Comment: @evayly The lastest version 3.2.4, you can paste the code into typescript playground.

Comment: @evayly Using `handlerList!.push(...)` did works, but still confused me. Why typescript it self still think `handlerList` can be `undefined`? It shouldn't be.

Comment: You didnt mention you've turned on `strictNullChecks`. The Algorithm behind that is still rather dumb. It seems like it doesnt like variables as array keys. Some smarter people could probably explain why this is. I am just leading you to this open issue with a similar and possibly related observation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29042

Comment: `type: P` => `type: extends EventType` => type can be anything. `handlerMap[anything]` IS possibly undefined.

Comment: @ritaj Yeah, `handlerMap[anything]` is possibly undefined, but `handlerMap[anything] || []` can NOT be undefined

Comment: Looks like a bug. Maybe you could [report it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)? Here is [a simplified code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20EventType%20%3D%20'click'%20%7C%20'dblclick'%0Aconst%20handlerMap%3A%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20EventType%5D%3F%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0Afunction%20addHandler%3CP%20extends%20EventType%3E(evType%3A%20P)%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20handlerList%20%3D%20handlerMap%5BevType%5D%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20handlerList.push(%7B%7D)%20%2F%2F%20Error%20here%3A%20Object%20is%20possibly%20'undefined'%0A%7D%0A).